# How to handle API subqueries in Flutter more faster?

Tags: node.js, flutter, async-await, sequelize.js, future

It's me again and suffering with async and await functions of Flutter! Since i begin with this i think i hate the Future ‍

Well, I'm developing an API REST with NodeJS and Sequelize, i was good until today. I have a cloud database with tables that contains a lot of relations with other tables, so these tables has different id fields. In this case, i'm working with materials_requisitions table, this table has various tables related. I brought all of the data of this table to my flutter app and drew it in one Screen. All OK but the user only can see id numbers on the widgets! So i made different async's getter functions to take the id of each field, search it in its corresponding table and return the information about that field completely. All is working well but it takes a lot of time!!!!

I have a list of materials_requisitions and i have to map field to field to show user more readable data.

Do you have any idea how to accelerate or do this subquerys more faster?? Or another way to do it better??

This is my solicitud_materiales.dart file, here i charge and draw the data:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:app_vivero/details/solicitud_materiales_detailN.dart';
import 'package:app_vivero/functions/api/requestHeadersToken.dart';
import 'package:app_vivero/functions/emptyBody.dart';
import 'package:app_vivero/functions/globals.dart';
import 'package:app_vivero/lists/GangsGetters.dart';import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import '../functions/globals.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import '../functions/navigationDrawer.dart';
import '../lists/DepartmentsGetters.dart';
import '../lists/EmployeesGetters.dart';
import '../lists/Materials_RequisitionsGetters.dart';

//lista de tipo de ejecuciones
const List<String> solicitud_tipo = <String>[
  'MATERIAL',
  'EPP',
  'DOTACION',
];

class Solicitud_MaterialesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Solicitud_MaterialesPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Solicitud_MaterialesPage> createState() => _Solicitud_MaterialesPageState();
}

class _Solicitud_MaterialesPageState extends State<Solicitud_MaterialesPage> {
  String dropdownValue = solicitud_tipo.first;
  int _paginaActual=0;
  String _page_title = "Jornal";
  List smList =[];
  List filteredList = [];
  //MAPEO DATOS LIST SM
  String department_name='';
  String gang_name='';
  String type_name='';
  String priority_name='';
  String employee_name='';


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title:  const Text('Solicitud de Materiales'),
      ),
      drawer: const navigationDrawerPersonalized(),
      body:Column(
        children:[
          Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
            child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            icon: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
              child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.cartShopping),
            ),
            labelText: "Tipo",
          ),
          hint: const Text("Seleccioná un tipo de solicitud"),
          value: dropdownValue,
          elevation: 16,
          onChanged: (String? value) {
            // This is called when the user selects an item.
            setState(() {
              dropdownValue = value!;
            });
          },
          items: solicitud_tipo.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((
              String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
      _body(),]),
    );
  }

  Widget _body() {
    switch (dropdownValue) {
      case 'MATERIAL':
        return MaterialSMBody('type_id',dropdownValue);
      case 'EPP':
        return MaterialSMBody('type_id',dropdownValue);
      case 'DOTACION':
        return MaterialSMBody('type_id',dropdownValue);
      default:
        return MaterialSMBody('type_id',dropdownValue);
    }//SWITCH
  }

  DataRow _getDataRow(index, data)  {
    return DataRow(
      cells: <DataCell>[
        DataCell(Text(data['sm_id'].toString(),style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.lightBlue,decoration: TextDecoration.underline),) , onTap: (){
          Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Solcitud_Materiales_Details(data['sm_id'])));
        }),
        DataCell(Text(data['date_record'])),
        DataCell(Text(data['type_id'].toString())),
        DataCell(Text(data['priority_id'].toString())),
        DataCell(Text(data['department_id'])),
        DataCell(Text(data['gang_id'].toString())),
        DataCell(Text(data['user_id'].toString())),
      ],
    );
  }

  //Traer planes con el metodo GET

  Future getSM() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var employeeId = prefs.getInt('employeeId');
    var company = prefs.getInt('userCompanyId');
    var result = await http.get(Uri.parse('$apiLink/materials_requisitions/list/$company/$employeeId'),headers: getTokenWithContentType(prefs));
    if (result.statusCode == 404){
      return showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
                actions: [
                  TextButton(
                      child: const Text('Aceptar'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      })
                ],
                icon: const Icon(Icons.warning,
                    color: Colors.yellow, size: 50.0),
                title: const Text('WARNING!'),
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                    40.0, 10.0, 40.0, 10.0),
                content:  Text(
                    result.body));
          });
    }else if (result.statusCode == 200) {
      List ModifiedSM = json.decode(result.body);
      for (var i = 0; i < ModifiedSM.length; i++) {
        ModifiedSM[i]['department_id'] =  await getListDepartment(ModifiedSM[i]['department_id']);
        ModifiedSM[i]['type_id'] =  await getListType(ModifiedSM[i]['type_id']);
        ModifiedSM[i]['priority_id'] =  await getListPriority(ModifiedSM[i]['priority_id']);
        ModifiedSM[i]['gang_id'] =  await getListGang(ModifiedSM[i]['gang_id']);
        ModifiedSM[i]['user_id'] =  await getListEmployee(ModifiedSM[i]['user_id']);
      }
      return ModifiedSM;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed');
    }
  }
  //TRAER DATOS DE DEPARTAMENTO PARA REEMPLAZARLOS POR ID EN LA LISTA
  getListDepartment(department_id) async {
      var department= await getDepartment(department_id);
         return department[0]['name'];
  }
//TRAER DATOS DE CUADRILLA PARA REEMPLAZARLOS POR ID EN LA LISTA
  getListGang(gang_id) async {
    var gang= await getGang(gang_id);
    return gang[0]['name'];
  }
  //TRAER DATOS DE TIPO DE SM PARA REEMPLAZARLOS POR ID EN LA LISTA
  getListType(type_id) async {
    var type= await getType(type_id);
    return type[0]['name'];
  }
  //TRAER DATOS DE PRIORIDAD DE SM PARA REEMPLAZARLOS POR ID EN LA LISTA
  getListPriority(priority_id) async {
    var priority= await getPriority(priority_id);
    return priority[0]['name'];
  }
  //TRAER DATOS DE EMPLEADO PARA REEMPLAZARLOS POR ID EN LA LISTA
  getListEmployee(employee_id) async {
    var employee= await getEmployee(employee_id);
    return employee[0]['first_name'] + " " + employee[0]['last_name'];
  }

  Widget MaterialSMBody(String filter_column, String filter_value){
    return GestureDetector(
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getSM(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              smList = snapshot.data;
              final filteredSM = smList.where((element) =>
              (element[filter_column] != null
                  ? element[filter_column] == (filter_value)
                  : false));
              filteredList = filteredSM.toList();
              return Column(children: [
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        DataTable(
                          // Datatable widget that have the property columns and rows.
                          columns: [
                            // Set the name of the column
                            const DataColumn(label: Text('SM #')),
                            const DataColumn(label: Text('FECHA')),
                            const DataColumn(label: Text('TIPO')),
                            DataColumn(
                              label: DropdownButton(
                                hint: const Text(
                                  'PRIORIDAD',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                ),
                                underline: Container(),
                                items: const [
                                  DropdownMenuItem(
                                    value: 'Urgente',
                                    child: Text('Urgente'),
                                  ),
                                  DropdownMenuItem(
                                    value: 'Requerida',
                                    child: Text('Requerida'),
                                  ),
                                ],
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  //Here update your column values

                                  setState(() {});
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                            const DataColumn(label: Text('DEPARTAMENTO')),
                            const DataColumn(label: Text('CUADRILLA')),
                            const DataColumn(label: Text('SOLICITANTE')),
                            //    const DataColumn(label: Text('APROBAR')),
                          ],
                          rows: List.generate(
                            filteredList.length,
                                (index) => _getDataRow(
                              index,
                                  filteredList[index],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),

                  ),
                ),
              ],
              );
            } else {
              return emptyBody();
            }
          }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is an example of the functions that i use to bring the departments, these are simple api requests:

```
//Traer datos de departamento en base al id brindado con el metodo http GET
Future getDepartment(int department_id) async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var result = await http.get(Uri.parse('$apiLink/departments/$department_id'),headers: getTokenWithContentType(prefs));
  if (result.statusCode == 200) {
    return json.decode(result.body);
  } else {
    throw Exception(result.body);
  }
}
```

Some screenshoots:

My SM screen

[image: 1]

It takes so much time!!

[image: 2]

Comment: Q: Approximately how long does the query take in your Flutter app?  Q: How long does the *SAME* query take with a DB client (like "sqlplus" or "ssms")?  Q: What is your DB?  MySql/MariaDB? MSSQL?  Oracle? Other?  Q: Have you done a "show plan" (or equivalent) in your DB?  Q: Since your " tables that contains a lot of relations with other tables" ... have you indexed the ID fields in each table?  Please [Edit] your post and provide additional details?

Comment: I don't know how much time it takes exactly. But like 40 secs - 1 min. This query doesn't exists in my DB because it's a find by ID query that i repeat in my app with a for loop. It's a SQL database, i don't understand the show plan?

Comment: Q: *WHAT* "SQL database":  MySql/MariaDB? MSSQL? Oracle?  Q: Do you have any client that can connect directly to the DB, independent of Flutter or NodeJS? If not, consider trying https://sqlectron.github.io/.  BASIC PROBLEM: If retrieving items stored in your database is "slow" ... then the FIRST place you need to look ... is your DATABASE.  If you're not already familiar with SQL, you should probably learn at least some basics.  If you're "looping through records" ... you can probably accomplish the SAME thing - much faster and more efficiently - with (server-side) SQL "SELECT" and "JOIN".

Comment: Sorry, is a MySQL databse, this database is on a Server and is connected with a scriptcase project, that project works with these tables id's, it reads and writes id's on the table but on the user side it presents the information with subquerys showing associated names of that id's. I was thinking about something like a local database that keeps the results of some of these querys and when it's necessary update the data from the cloud database, or something like that, idk, a way to keep the results of these specific querys somewhere. What do you think about that?

Comment: This querys are common in the project, so i can reuse them in various screens, so I want to keep the value of them to paint them along all my app. Apart from that and answering your question i have MySQL workbench in my computer to manage the db.